# Ionic lazy loading a module within children array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, lazy-loading, angular-routing, ionic4

I have an Ionic application with a `List Page Module` and a `Subdir Page Module` underneath the `Page module`. Here is the folder structure ---> `list/subdir.`

[image]

**Problem**: I have the problem of `List page module` always loading when I navigate to `localhost:8100/list/subdir` instead of the `Subdir page` loading.

[image]

**Outcome**: I want the `Subdir page` to load when I navigate to `localhost:8100/list/subdir`; but instead it loads `List page`. I only want to load `List page` when URL is `localhost:8100/list`

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    loadChildren: './list/list.module#ListPageModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**list.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ListPage } from './list.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: ListPage,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'subdir',
            loadChildren: './subdir/subdir.module#SubdirPageModule',

          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ListPage]
})
export class ListPageModule {}
```

Comment: Did you mean that you see "List" component instead of the "Subdir" component when you visit ...../subdir? Or did you mean that you see the List module loading even when you visit ...../subdir?

Comment: @UğurDinç I see List component when I go to list/subdir, but that is wrong. I want to see the Subdir component when i visit list/subdir

Answer (score 1):

Any time you have a route inside a children array of another route, both the child and the parent component will be injected to the template.

This is because the parent would be using the < router-outlet > at (e.g) the global level (could be in app.component.html), and the child component would be using the < router-outlet > at its parents template. So, you would end up displaying both components at the same time.

If you are interested in not seeing the parent component in the view, you need to get rid of the parent-child relationship between the List and the Subdir.

To do that, you would have two options:

1) Move ListPage component to child route e.g list/list

or

2) Move Subdir component to an upper level.

Comment: But what if I want the List module to be a module where i hold multiple other sub-modules. Like parent children relationship. List is parent and Subdir is child. So that's why I want to keep it in the List module. Basically a URL structure like so `parent/child1` , `parent/child2` and so on...

Comment: @user1142130 Then you need to follow the option #1. Move all the HTML inside the ListComponent to a ListItemComponent, and leave only the < router-outlet > inside it. This way, you will only display Subdir for ...../subdir (since there will be nothing but the < router-outlet > at the parent template), and you would only display the ListItem when the route is list/items

Comment: Ok, if I do that, then what if i have another parent module, for example `home` and that one has a `subdir` as well. so now i have `list/subdir` and `home/subdir` . will they conflict with each other? or is each `subdir` relative only to its parent, either `list` or `home`

Comment: Won't conflict since they are two separate routes. Both routes will go and check what component / module they are mapped to and load accordingly.

Comment: Hmm , I don't want to create a ListItem module though. Let me explain with different example. I have a module called `User`. Inside of this module there is a `UserRegistration` module. So `User` is the parent, and `RegisterUser` is the child. So i want to have a URL like this `example.com/user/registeruser` . So, in my example above, the User would be the List. And Subdir would be RegisterUser

Comment: Again, if you don't want to see the User in the browser during user/registeruser, then you gota make sure there is either no parent-child relationship, or there is no HTML inside the User other than router-outelet.